# Filter queryset between two or more models for search form in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Im building a search form in django, Im doing it with filter querysets, this form is like a "advance search form", I mean, form could has more than two inputs, but problem is that each input corresponding of a field of different model, I have this and works fine if the form only has one input for one model:

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        buscar_predio = request.POST['nombre_predio']
        query1 = InfoPredioGeneral.objects.filter(nombre_predio__iexact=buscar_predio)
        if query1:
            ctx  = {'predio':query1}
            return render(request,'resultados_busqueda.html',ctx)
        else:
            return render(request,'resultados_busqueda.html')
```

If I have this models:

```
class InfoPredioGeneral(models.Model):
        nombre_predio = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Propietario(models.Model):
        predio = models.ForeignKey(InfoPredioGeneral,blank=True,null=True,related_name='predio_propietario+')
        tipo_identificacion = models.ForeignKey(TipoIdentificacion,related_name='tipo identificacion+',blank=True,null=True)
```

In the post method how can I search in the same form a `InfoPredioGeneral` and `Propietario`? For example filter where nombre_predio is exact to "predio proof" and where tipo_`identificacion` is exacto to "123"? As you can see `Propietario` has a `ForeignKey` to `InfoPredioGeneral`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for a many-to-one relationship

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

you already set the related_name to "predio_propietario+" and with the '+' at the end this means there is no backwards relation to this model

there is you example:

```
queryset = Propietario.objects.filter(predio__nombre_predio__iexact=request.POST['nombre_predio'])
```

Extra:

```
class C(models.Model):
    c_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
    b_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

queryset will look like this:

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(b_btext__isexact="your b text", c_ctext__isexact="your c text")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works... But if I'd have a thrid model with a ForeignKey to InfoPredioGeneral and I need to make a relation among three, how would be?

Comment: you mean you have model "A" content ForeignKey of model "B" and model "B" content ForeignKey "C"? or model "A" content both ForeignKey of model "B" and "C"?

Comment: Second option, model "A" content both  ForeignKey of model "B" and "C"?